# Linq - getting root descendants

Tags: c#, xml, linq

The xml file is this one:

```
<settings y="1" x="0">
    <prospect aksdj="sdf">
        <image path="images/1.jpg"/>
    </prospect>
    <prospect aksdfasdj="safafdf">
        <image path="images/2.jpg"/>
    </prospect>
</settings>
```

I want to get both rows with the image tags.

My code is this:

```
 XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\John\Desktop\File.xml");
 var result = (from c in doc.Descendants("settings")
                      select new
                      {
                          name = c.Element("prospect").Value
                      }).ToList();
```

But, doc.Descendants("settings") is null. Why is it null?

Comment: Your sample XML is broken, btw - the last line should be a closing tag. How representative is it of your real file?

Comment: Sorry, when I shortened the file to put it here I mistakenly erased it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've loaded an *element* which is already the `<settings>` element - that *element* doesn't have any `<settings>` descendants. (`Descendants` isn't returning you `null`, by the way - it's returning you an empty sequence. There's a big difference.)

If you change it to

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("...");
```

then it should be okay - or just load it as an `XElement` and find the `<prospect>` descendants, given that you've only got one `<settings>` element anyway...

Comment: I found the <prospect> descendants and it's ok :)